# Redirect URL to a specific page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a plugin, in which I send newsletters to subscribed users. To do this, I first created a form, in which users enter their email-id, and been subscribed. After subscribing, they got an email for confirming their email-id. Here is the problem arise.

To confirm, I send them a link for confirming their email id as following:

```
http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin-path/templates/subscribe.php?id=53cad9f23a6ec
```

While I have to send them the link as following:

```
http://localhost/wordpress/newsletter/confirmation/53cad9f23a6ec
```

So how it can be done. Please help me. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You should include the related code.